# How is it possible for a string to be typed as Number in npm package commandLineArgs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, command-line, types

In the below code from [MongoDB's course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/MongoDB/M101JS/2016_August/courseware/) Week 3's **Query Operators in the Node.js Driver** chapter :

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args'),
  assert = require('assert');


var options = commandLineOptions();

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crunchbase', function(err, db) {

  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

  var query = queryDocument(options);
  var projection = {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "founded_year": 1,
    "number_of_employees": 1,
    "crunchbase_url": 1
  };

  var cursor = db.collection('companies').find(query, projection);
  var numMatches = 0;

  cursor.forEach(
    function(doc) {
      numMatches = numMatches + 1;
      console.log(doc);
    },
    function(err) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Our query was:" + JSON.stringify(query));
      console.log("Matching documents: " + numMatches);
      return db.close();
    }
  );

});

function queryDocument(options) {

  console.log(options);

  var query = {
    "founded_year": {
      "$gte": options.firstYear,
      "$lte": options.lastYear
    }
  };

  if ("employees" in options) {
    query.number_of_employees = {
      "$gte": options.employees
    };
  }

  return query;

}

function commandLineOptions() {

  var cli = commandLineArgs([{
    name: "firstYear",
    alias: "f",
    type: Number
  }, {
    name: "lastYear",
    alias: "l",
    type: Number
  }, {
    name: "employees",
    alias: "e",
    type: Number
  }]);

  var options = cli.parse()
  if (!(("firstYear" in options) && ("lastYear" in options))) {
    console.log(cli.getUsage({
      title: "Usage",
      description: "The first two options below are required. The rest are optional."
    }));
    process.exit();
  }

  return options;

}
```

I'm requiring `command-line-args` package, which has a method `commandLineArgs`. All good and fine...

Now, I see that the `type` of the objects passed to this method is set to `Number`. We can clearly see that they're `String`s.

How is it possible?

Comment: parseInt(stringVar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`command-line-args` GitHub page](https://github.com/75lb/command-line-args#optiontype--function):

> The `type` value is a setter function (you receive the output from this), enabling you to be specific about the type and value received.

In other words, passing `Number` as type allows you to parse the arguments as numbers.

Comment: Oh thanks for clearing this out. So, it is referring to the input from the end user, right?